# Should I always use a reverse proxy for a web app?

Tags: http, web-applications, nginx, go, reverse-proxy

I'm writing a web app in Go. Currently I have a layout that looks like this:

[CloudFlare] --> [Nginx] --> [Program]

Nginx does the following:

- Performs some redirects (i.e. `www.domain.tld` --> `domain.tld`)
- Adds headers such as `X-Frame-Options`.
- Handles static images.
- Writes `access.log`.

In the past I would use Nginx as it performed SSL termination and some other tasks. Since that's now handled by CloudFlare, all it does, essentially, is static images. Given that Go has a built in HTTP FileServer and CloudFlare could take over handling static images for me, I started to wonder why Nginx is in-front in the first place.

Is it considered a bad idea to put nothing in-front?

Answer (score 7):

In your case, you can possibly get away with not running nginx, but I wouldn't recommend it.

However, as I touched on [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17461472/556573) there's still a lot it can do that you'll need to "reinvent" in Go.

- Content-Security headers
- SSL (is the connection between CloudFlare and you insecure if they are terminating SSL?)
- SSL session caching & HSTS
- Client body limits and header buffers
- 5xx error pages and maintenance pages when you're restarting your Go application
- "Free" logging (unless you want to write all that in your Go app)
- gzip (again, unless you want to implement that in your Go app)

Running Go standalone makes sense if you are running an internal web service or something lightweight, or genuinely don't need the extra features of nginx. If you're building web applications then nginx is going to help abstract "web server" tasks from the application itself.

Comment: Hmm, good point about terminating at CloudFlare. Yeah, a MITM on the line between CloudFlare and the server would be able to read everything in plaintext. CloudFlare does let you use a "Full" SSL implementation where both ends are encrypted. I imagine my end can have a self-signed cert. I haven't signed up for Pro yet so I don't know enough to comment fully.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use nginx at all to be honest, some nice dude tested fast `cgi` `go` + `nginx` and just go standalone library. The results he came up with were quite interesting, the standalone hosting seemed to be much better in handling requests than using it behind `nginx`, and the final recommendation was that if you don't need specific features of nginx don't use it. [full article](https://gist.github.com/hgfischer/7965620)

You could run it as standalone and if you're using partial/full `ssl` on your site you could use another go `http` server to redirect to safe `https` routes.

Comment: nginx was barely behind Go itself in that benchmark (39k req/a vs 42k req/s) on the single process benchmark. The benchmark results don't really impact most users: few of us will hit 75k req/s, but most of us can leverage nginx's extra features.

Comment: I didn't have context about what OP is trying to do or know much about how many users he is going to serve. If you have any reasons why OP should use nginx please feel free to add your answer.

Comment: @YasirG I'm not sure how many users (few thousand?). As for context, I'm not sure what other information would be helpful. This will be a free service for the public -- not something sitting on my raspberry pi at home. It'll probably quite a few users but no persistent/long-lived connections. Bandwidth is going to be quite low (no video).

I suppose you can imagine it gets slashdotted / posted to HN's frontage. How much traffic is that?

Comment: @Mark frankly all the important features e.g. gzip, error handling, and logging already exist in some frameworks like falcore: http://fitstar.github.io/falcore/ and beego: http://beego.me, so there is no 'reinventing the wheel' moment here... 99% of the time you can find the tools you need in some framework. I'd say give it a shot before you resort to nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ngnix if you do not need it.
Go does SSL in less lines then you have to write in ngnix configure file.
The only reason is a free logging but I wonder how many lines of code is logging in Go.
There is nice [article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/197570/) in Russian about reverse proxy in Go in 200 lines of code.
If Go could be used instead of ngnix then ngnix is not required when you use Go.
You need ngnix if you wish to have several Go processes or Go and PHP on same site.
Or if you use Go and you have some problem when you add ngnix then it fix the problem.