# How to host go application on dedicated server, without using google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is it possible to host a go application on apache/nginx server ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course. You can use Go's built in web-server directly (which is very capable), or sit behind a nginx/Apache reverse proxy if you so wish.

I run my Go application behind nginx, and use supervisord to manage logging, restarting and managing my Go application.

Take a look at these two answers for some more details: [Golang production web application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440415/golang-production-web-application-configuration/17461472#17461472) and [Webserver for Go (golang) webservices: using NGINX or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776584/webserver-for-go-golang-webservices-using-nginx-or-not/17777630#17777630)